# Splitting a number at commas and populating an array gone wrong

Tags: java, android

Background: I have a number 1000. My desired result is to input 1000 to a function and get "1 thousand" as output. I am using 1000 just as an example the function can do this with any number.

First I take this number and put commas:

```
public String formatNumbers(String input) {

        String number = input;
        double dispString = Double.parseDouble(number);
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
        return (formatter.format(dispString));

    }
```

This returns me the number with commas that is 1,000. I store this into a variable called `numberwithcommas`

Second I convert the number into words [using this code](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0426.html) exactly as it is. I name this variable as `originalNum`

Now I split and add to array the `numberwithcommas`

```
String[] parts = originalNum.split(",");
```

Next I assign a new variable:

```
String startNum = parts[0];
```

this gives me the first half of my results (the digits), 1 in this case.

Now I convert the `startNum` into words using the same class & strategy as mentioned above in case of `originalNum`

This assigns the string `One` to a variable I define as `replace`

```
String replace = NumberToWords.start(Integer.valueOf(startNum));
```

Now my explosives are ready I use a simple replace strategy

I replace `One` from `One Thousand` with an empty string:

```
String second_half_words = numberInWords.replace(replace, " ");
```

SO at this point my `second_half_words` is equal to `Thousand`
Now I concatenate startNum and second_half_words to build my final string. I get a proper result. However a bug report of my application is as follows:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "10 000 000"
at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:489)
at com.exs.FragmentTab1$CurAdapter.displayStats(FragmentTab1.java:768)
```

The line number 768 refers to

```
String replace = NumberToWords.start(Integer.valueOf(startNum));
```

line in my code, I am totally puzzled as how the value of startNum can ever be "10 000 000" at this point. What must be wrong here?

Below is the whole code:

```
public void displayStats(String number){
    long intnumber = Long.valueOf(number); 

    String numberwithcommas = formatNumbers(number); 
    String numberInWords = NumberToWords.start(intnumber);
    String originalNum = numberwithcommas;
    String[] parts = originalNum.split(",");
    System.out.println("Parts"+Arrays.toString(parts));
    String startNum = parts[0]; //This is the top text
    System.out.println("Parts2"+startNum);
    String replace = NumberToWords.start(Integer.valueOf(startNum));
    String second_half_words = numberInWords.replace(replace, " "); 

    setDispStatsPart1(startNum);
    setDispStatswords(second_half_words);
}

public String dispStatsPart1(){

    return part1+"\n"; 
}

public String dispStatswords(){
    if(finnumberInWords.length() <= 1){
        return ""; 
    }else{
        return finnumberInWords+"\n"; 
    }
}

public void setDispStatsPart1(String part){
    part1 = part.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
}

public void setDispStatswords(String words){
    finnumberInWords = words.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
}

public String formatNumbers(String input) {

    String number = input;
    double dispString = Double.parseDouble(number);
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
    return (formatter.format(dispString));

}
```

### EDIT

I am not sure what the input to this function must have been when the bug report was captured. But I am sure of `Invalid int: "10 000 000"` occuring at line number 768 which refers to

`String replace = NumberToWords.start(Integer.valueOf(startNum));` in my code.

Here is the original stack trace as reported on my Dev console:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "10 000 000"
at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:489)
at com.exd.FragmentTab1$CurAdapter.displayStats(FragmentTab1.java:768)
at com.exd.FragmentTab1$CurAdapter.bindView(FragmentTab1.java:4158)
at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:254)
at com.exd.FragmentTab1$CurAdapter.getView(FragmentTab1.java:746)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2301)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1801)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:697)
at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1360)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1631)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2157)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14981)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4790)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14981)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4790)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14981)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4790)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:887)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14981)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4790)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14981)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4790)
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14981)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4790)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14981)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4790)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1997)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1752)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1005)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5647)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You can see following link http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/java/13.htm

Comment: I dont think it is a problem with my number to words conversion. I am very sure about that.